# extract data from stardict syn file

Tags: extract

I'm trying to extract data from a startdict syn file.

I'm trying to convert a data file:

```
> file Babylon_Korean_English.syn
Babylon_Korean_English.syn: data
```

into a plain text file.

The file can be found here: http://abloz.com/huzheng/stardict-dic/babylon/bidirectional/stardict-babylon-Babylon_Korean_English-2.4.2.tar.bz2 within the tar.bz2

I'd lke to be able to extract lines from the file, but currently if I do, for example:

```
> grep 느려 Babylon_Korean_English.syn
```

I only get the response:

```
Binary file Babylon_Korean_English.syn matches
```

rather than being able to find the entire line or to search for a number of characters before and after the file.

I've also tried:

```
> strings Babylon_Korean_English.syn
```

which outputs nothing.

trying to output the first line with 'head' gives the text like the following:

```
...�간헐적일거야�간헐적일거예요...
```

I'd like to be able to look at the text file without the little � all over the place.

Information on the file format is as follows:

from http://www.stardict.org/StarDictFileFormat

{4}. The ",syn" file's format.
This file is optional, and you should notice tree dictionary needn't this file.
Only StarDict-2.4.8 and newer support this file.

The .syn file contains information for synonyms, that means, when you input a 
synonym, StarDict will search another word that related to it.

The format is simple. Each item contain one string and a number.
synonym_word;  // a utf-8 string terminated by '\0'.
original_word_index; // original word's index in .idx file.
Then other items without separation.
When you input synonym_word, StarDict will search original_word;

The length of "synonym_word" should be less than 256. In other 
words, (strlen(word) < 256).
original_word_index is a 32-bits unsigned number in network byte order.
Two or more items may have the same "synonym_word" with different 
original_word_index.
The items must be sorted by stardict_strcmp() with synonym_word.

Comment: What language are you using to parse it? What have you attempted so far? What isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to parse the syn file by downloading the BGL file, and then using pyglossary to create a new syn file, modified like so:

```
./pyglossary > git diff pyglossary/plugins/stardict.py
diff --git a/pyglossary/plugins/stardict.py b/pyglossary/plugins/stardict.py
@@ -392,7 +392,7 @@ class StarDictWriter:
-                synStr += item[0] + '\x00' + intToBinStr(item[1], 4)
+                synStr += item[0] + ' ' + str(item[1]) + "\n"
```

This worked for my purposes, since I still had access to the .bgl file.